# where to place dataset file for plotting in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I've seen many tutorials about plotting data in gnu plot, but I haven't found out where should I place my dataset file for plotting. In many tutorials there is a command like "plot 'example.dat'", but where this example.dat file is really placed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gnuplot tries to find file in current folder. If you launch gnuplot via terminal then the current folder will be current for gnuplot too. Inside gnuplot you can change path with `cd 'path/to/datafiledir'`. To see current directory inside gnuplot you can use `pwd`

Comment: default folder for placing .dat files is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin'

Comment: You can also specify a full path to the file.  Note that on windows, you need to use double slashes (to escape the slash) when typing the path: `plot 'c:\\users\\myself\\documents\\gnuplotdata\\datafile.dat'`.